# How to delete an item from a list in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the List.js file im trying to remove each item from the list

Currently within App.js i have a button within the section that is able to delete all birthdays by passing in a empty array.

```
**App.js**

import React, { useState } from "react";
import data from "./data";
import List from "./List";

function App() {
 
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(data);
  return (
    <main>
      <section className="container">
        <h3>{people.length} birthdays today!</h3>
        <List people={people} />
        <button onClick={() => setPeople([])}> Clear Birthdays </button>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
**List.js**

import React from "react";

const List = ({ people }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {people.map((person) => {
        const { id, name, age, image } = person;
        return (
          <article key={id} className="person">
            <img src={image} alt={name} />
            <div>
              <h4>{name}</h4>
              <p>{age}</p>
            </div>
          </article>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default List;
```

I tried creating a new function and button with an arrow function in the List.js that passes in id like so

```
  const removeItem = (id) => {
    let newPeople = people.filter((person) => person.id !== id);
    setPeople(newPeople);
  };

<button onClick={() => removeItem(id}>Clear</button>
```

**refactored code working solution below**

```
*** App.Js ***
import React, { useState } from "react";
import data from "./data";
import List from "./List";

function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(data);
  const removeItem = (id) => {
    let newPeople = people.filter((person) => person.id !== id);
    setPeople(newPeople);
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <section className="container">
        <h3>{people.length} birthdays today!</h3>
        <List people={people} removeItem={removeItem} />
        <button onClick={() => setPeople([])}> Clear Birthdays </button>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
*** List.js ***
import React from "react";

const List = ({ people, removeItem }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {people.map((person) => {
        const { id, name, age, image } = person;
        return (
          <article key={id} className="person">
            <img src={image} alt={name} />
            <div>
              <h4>{name}</h4>
              <p>{age}</p>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => removeItem(id)}>Clear</button>
          </article>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default List;
```

request for comments for different solutions.

Comment: Edited the title, it was wrong but im trying to remove a single item from the list, currently able to delete all items.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass your removeItem function to the List component:

```
return (
    <main>
      <section className="container">
        <h3>{people.length} birthdays today!</h3>
        <List people={people} removeItem={removeItem} />
        <button onClick={() => setPeople([])}> Clear Birthdays </button>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
```

And call it when the button is clicked and pass the person's id to the function

Comment: Thanks for the feedback that worked out! Need more reputation to cast a vote.